# No module named "numpy" (and tensorflow) even though installed

Tags: python, numpy, module, pip

I have been struggling on this for a while without prevail. I am trying to run a test script with

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([1,2,3])
```

However, I get the error "No module named 'numpy'". The same goes for Tensorflow.
But trying "pip install numpy" on terminal gives "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.23.4)".

And when I move the script to another directory, in which I already have ran Numpy in, it runs without error. Why does the Numpy module (also Tensorflow) work in that directory, but not in the new one I created?

Tried to uninstall and install Numpy in Terminal

Comment: Uninstall both(numpy and Tensorflow)... install tensorflow first....tensorflow has numpy dependency so it will installed along with numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `pip install` and run scripts in the right python environment (can be `python-venv` or `conda` env), you can troubleshoot these with `which python` and `which pip` or `pip --version`

You can create `venv` with

```bash
python3 -m venv env
```

and make sure you are in the correct python environment by activate it:

```bash
source env/bin/activate
```

only then you will install `numpy` and other library **inside this virtualenv**

```bash
pip3 install numpy
```

Later on, when you run scripts from this project, make sure you `cd` into its directory, then `source env/bin/activate` before running scripts or `pip install <libraries>`.